# homogenous matrix equation Ax = 0

Tags: linear-algebra

Do anyone have an ide how to solve this problem?

I tried something like invers, but seems not to succeed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row reduction preserves the solution space. This solution space can be easily read off from the reduced matrix: the bottom three lines yield no information, and the first line tells you that $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ satisfies $Ax = 0$ if and only if $x_2 = 0$. Therefore the solution space is $3$-dimensional and spanned by $(1,0,0,0)$, $(0,0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what equations in $x_1, \ldots, x_4$ does this correspond to?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1 = r$, $x_3 = s$, $x_4 = t$.

Then $x_2=0$ (from the augmented matrix).

So the general solution would be:

${\bf{0}}=\pmatrix{r \\ 0 \\ s \\ t}$

where you can let $r$, $s$ and $t$ be anything.

So the solution space would have 3 dimensions.